# How would I administer my linksys router through ssh?

Tags: ssh, router, administration

Most of the administrative tasks required some http service used over a web browser.  Is there a way to perform adiminstrative tasks to my router through ssh?  Sometimes having a GUI is not possible (especially if you have headless linux server that only has ssh as your only avenue to connect).  I happen to own the wrt54g model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use third-party firmware such as [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato/) or [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/site/index) to enable such remote management.

I have no experience with Tomato, but remote SSH administration with DD-WRT has worked great on my Buffalo router. You're in luck; the WRT54G is one of the most supported models for many third-party firmwares.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried curl? In theory, curl should be all you need. You can also try a text-based browser such as lynx, if you don't like switching the os of the router.

Comment: *In practice*, many routers have web UIs overloaded with tables and JavaScript, making them near-unusable by anything other but modern graphical web browsers.

Comment: elinks has some javascript support. however, i do agree that full functionality is likely only available with a gui browser. but for some simple tasks such as getting a list of client ips, it is possible with curl and text browser.